# How to Draw Multiple geometry (Polygon) on google map Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, polygon, google-maps-android-api-2

hi i am getting data of more than 1 polygon data from my database, I want to draw all that polygon on my google map. my code is working but it only drawing the last polygon not all the below is the code i used to implement this.

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void showAllLocationsOnMap(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d("dataa", "datasise " + allLocationsData.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < allLocationsData.size(); i++) {
        LocationDataModel locationDataModel = allLocationsData.get(i);
        List<LatLng> polygonLatLng = locationDataModel.getLatLngList();
        googleMap.addPolygon(addpoly(polygonLatLng));
    }
}

    public PolygonOptions addpoly(List<LatLng> arg) {

    PolygonOptions polygonOptions;
    polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    polygonOptions.addAll(arg).strokeColor(Color.RED).strokeWidth(2);
    polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.parseColor("#51000000"));
    return polygonOptions;
}
```

please read the code properly. and ask if you have any counter question. and help me to implement it.

Comment: As rhe code looks correct I would check if the allocationsData really contains different polygons, or if the error already happens when filling this list.

Comment: allocationsData  contain all the data of differnt polygons i check it using logd

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is outside of the shown code. Try to replace the for loop with two calls of addPolygon(addPoly(....)) and pass two different short and manually created lists of LatLng to addPoly. Check if both polygons  are drawn.

Comment: yes you was right the actual problem in data base helper function. this code is now working perfectly fine. Thank you